# Azure container registry + MSI (in service fabric) - is it possible?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-container-registry, azure-managed-identity

Here's the setup:

- Azure Container Registry
- Service Fabric

  - VMSS with SystemAssigned identity (aka "Managed Service Identity" aka MSI)
  - VMSS identity given "Reader" role access to the Azure Container Registry
- ApplicationManifest.xml

  - ServiceManifest.xml referencing a container in the registry

Cool.

Except service fabric can't launch instances of the app because it can't pull the container from the registry.  When I RDP into a VM and pull, it tells me "authentication required"

I understand that I can add <RepositoryCredentials …> into my ApplicationManifest.xml.  With my password.  To the container admin account.  Which seems "bad", even if encrypted.  Definitely less convenient than having MSI working.

Working locally, MSI works fine after a couple little **az acr** commands.

Can it all be wrapped up somehow in the ApplicationManifest/ServiceManifest.xml files, so that MSI is honored when pulling from Azure Container Registry?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think you can, at least not as an official approach, You can try running the az acr commands as a SetupEntryPoint to authenticate and then omit the credentials on App manifest to use the cached credentials. Not sure it will work, but is how you should do without SF.